# Register Spark UDF Java8 way

Tags: java, apache-spark, udf

Can someone help me with a small problem?

When I register spark UDF using lambda expression

```
sqlContext.udf().register("calc_age", (Date dob) -> calculateAge(dob), IntegerType);
```

Everything works fine and no compilation errors occur. But when I try to do the same registration using function reference it fails, saying it can't determine types of UDF. Can it be fixed and if not - why?

```
sqlContext.udf().register("calc_age", SomeMainClass::calculateAge, IntegerType);
```